# Encoding problems with CSV export from Excel

Tags: php, silex

I have an encoding problem with Microsoft Excel CSV exports. I created an import method which reads a CSV file containing contacts to push them to our database.

Here is my process

1. When I `save as` from Microsoft Excel to create a CSV file which contains unicode characters like `è`, I have my generated CSV file.
2. When I upload it through POSTMAN and then I read the content of the temp file with `fread`, `file` or `file_get_contents`, I have some bad characters.

When I use LibreOffice (https://fr.libreoffice.org/), all is good and I have into my PHP code the good encoding.

I tried many solutions as far as I could do like `mb_convert_encoding`, `utf8_encode`, `iconv` but nothing would work.

That's what I get from my var_dump

[image: Var_dump]

That's my code which converts the file's content into an array to iterate over the lines in order to convert a line into an array.

```
$iterableContacts = Closure::bind(function () use ($filePath) {
    $keys = [
        'email',
        'language',
        'lastname',
        'firstname',
        'organization',
        'job',
        'street',
        'street_complement',
        'zipcode',
        'city',
        'country',
        'note'
    ];

    // var_dump(file($filePath));

    foreach (file($filePath, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES|FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) as $key => $line) {
        $line = str_getcsv($line, ';');

        if (trim(strtolower($line[0])) == 'email') {
            continue;
        } elseif (count($line) === count($keys) && !empty($line)) {
            yield ($key - 1) => array_combine($keys, array_values($line));
        }
    }
}, null);
```

`mb_detect_encoding` returns me `ASCII`

Anyone can help me please?

Microsoft Excel 2016 build 15.26 (160910)
PHP 5.6.28-1

Comment: When you do your var_dump(), where do you display it?

Comment: I display it into POSTMAN through the preview response. Note that debugging my CSV from LibreOffice in the preview response correctly shows me my content

Comment: Why should you care what some encoding guesser detects? Save the file with an encoding of your choosing and read it with that very same encoding. If you loose track of which encoding a file is saved with then you have data loss. So, which encoding are you telling Excel to use when writing the file? (Presumably you'd choose one for a character set that supports all the characters you could possibly use.)

Comment: Our customers use Excel and some other softwares to manage their own contacts. We export their contacts in a CSV with the UTF-8 encoding but when they open it through Excel and save it, the encoding is lost on the upload even if they set the UTF-8 encoding on Excel :/

Comment: Excel oversimplifies the process of opening a CSV file. Instead of "Open", create a new Workbook and use Data » Get External Data » From Text File and answer the questions from the Text Import Wizard. To save, use Save As » Save as file of Type: CSV UTF-8…. (It prepends the text with a UTF-8 BOM. Try testing if a BOM helps Excel with "Open".)